# How to center a row with text and inputs

Tags: html, css

I have a row with text and input text fields and I want the text above the text feild and wanted everything centered. Should I make a div for everything and center that? or just center each row individually? Any help?

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="modal-body">

  <!-- test for NEW CONTENT AREA -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">username*</h6>
      <input align="middle" class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">firstname*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">lastname*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">password*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">confirm password*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="/img/siloutte.png" align="middle" alt="add image" width="110px" height="80px" />
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label for="contact"><span><h5>* required field</h5></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try text-align:center to .modal-body?

Comment: yes, I added text-align to the modal-body class.  Seen here:    .modal-body .section-header {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 
 text-align:center;
}  and it still does not center it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mh3tf1fd/)

I added some CSS:

```css
.modal-body {
  text-align:center;    
}
```

Comment: I tried this and centers the text within the input text feild, not witin the modal-body.

Comment: And i still need username and the input feild to be above first and last name.   First and last name need to be next to each other as do password and confirm pass.  So i just want to push everything to the center.

Comment: I believe I need to center the row? Not sure

Comment: so you want bot the Firstname and Lastname div to be next to each other in the same row?

Comment: correct.  i have it set up the way I want it, i just need it all to be centered.  First/last are in the same row and pass and confirm are in another row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want for the fields on the same line: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mh3tf1fd/2/)

```
<div id="block_container">
<div id="block1" style="float:left">
     <h6 class="section-header">firstname*</h6>

    <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true" />
</div>
<div id="bloc2" style="float:right">
     <h6 class="section-header">lastname*</h6>

    <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true" />
</div>
```

Comment: this does not work.  I see in your result section that it isnt center as well.  Still seems like the content is stuck to the left most side and even align it to the right it doesnt go fully to the right of the modal

Answer (score 0):

So all I had to do was use `.col-sm-6` instead of `4`. That increases the length of the text field and makes it fit better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-content to constrain the width and subsequently center the element by setting left and right margins to auto.

```css
.modal-body {
    width: min-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">

  <!-- test for NEW CONTENT AREA -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">username*</h6>
      <input align="middle" class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">firstname*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">lastname*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">password*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h6 class="section-header">confirm password*</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="assignment-name" ng-model="assignment.name" ng-required="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="/img/siloutte.png" align="middle" alt="add image" width="110px" height="80px" />
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label for="contact"><span><h5>* required field</h5></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```